# How do I autoload old class names in PHP Zend 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, psr-0

How do I autoload the class `Google_Client` in Zend 2?

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses Composer you can use it's classmap autoloader to spider any directory and add all the classes it finds to the autoloader:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

If your project uses the built-in autoloader of Zend Framework (`Zend\Loader`) [check out it's documentation here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.loader.autoloader-factory.html#quick-start).  By default it does PSR-0 autoloading, but `Zend\Loader` also supports classmap autoloading ([docs here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.loader.class-map-autoloader.html)).  For an example of using `Zend\Loader` in a ZF2 module [check out the Application module of ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php#L34)